# cast to pointer from integer of different size

Tags: c, pointers

**I keep getting this warning**

> c:9:80: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
>
> printf("Char= %c    ASCII = %i    hex = %x    pointer = %p  \n", i, i, i , (void*)i );

Code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int *i;
    for (int i = 75; i < 75 + 26; i++) {
        printf("Char= %c    ASCII = %i    hex = %x    pointer = %p  \n", i, i, i , (void*)i ); 
    }
    return(0); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fail to see what the question might be that is not answered by the compiler warning. You've got a variable "i" of type `int` (32 bit on 64 bit platforms), shadowing another variable called "i" in the main program.

You're casting the `int` variable to `void*`, and the compiler says you can't do that, because you are 32 bit short. Rename one of the two variables called `i` in your program to resolve.

Comment: ah ok, i was not quit sure what was causing the warning and how i was supposed to resolve the issue. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You’re getting the warning because the variable “i” is declared twice in the same scope. The memory address of ‘i’ in your loop doesn’t change so what do you need the pointer outside the loop for?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    for (int i = 75; i < 75 + 26; i++) {
        printf("Char= %c    ASCII = %i    hex = %x    pointer = %p  \n", i, i, i , &i );
    }
   return(0);
}
```

or yet still if you still want to have two variables.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int i;
int *j = &i;

int main (void) {
for ( i = 75; i < 75 + 26; i++) {
    printf("Char= %c    ASCII = %i    hex = %x    pointer = %p  \n", i, i, i , (void *)j );
}
return(0);
}
```